# Assign an individual in a dataset to a particular state based on predetermined proportions in R

Tags: r, random, dplyr

I have data which looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(
age_grp10 = rep(c("00-09", "10-19", "20-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-59", "60-    69", "70-79", "80-89"), 2),
sex = c(rep("M", 9), rep("F", 9)),
prob_arr = round((runif(18, min = 0.11, max = 2.50)), digits = 2),
prob_dep = round((runif(18, min = 0.11, max = 2.50)), digits = 2)
)
```

This dataset gives the proportion of people, by age and gender, who arrive or depart in a calendar year.

Then I have population level data, which looks like this

```
  pop_df <- data.frame(
  uniq_ID = c("AFG1234", "WED1234", "POJ1234", "DER234", "QWE1234", "BGR1234", "ABC1234", "DSE1234", "UHJ1234", "POI234",
          "EDC1234", "BGT1234", "MJI1234", "WEX1234", "FGH1234", "UJN1234", "LOK1234", "DRT1234", "URD1234", "MVR1234"),
  age_grp10 = c("50-59", "40-49", "20-29", "40-49", "00-09",  "50-59", "30-39", "70-79",  "60-69", "40-49",
            "80-89", "10-19", "30-39", "30-39", "50-59", "70-79", "00-09", "70-79", "20-29", "20-29"),
  sex = c("M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F"))
```

In this population dataset, each row is an individual, for about 5 million people. It shows their age and gender, and unique ID number. 
Based on the proportions in the first dataframe (df), I would like to assign arrival and departure status to the individuals in the population dataframe (pop_df).

My desired output would look like

```
pop_df <- pop_df %>%
left_join(df) %>%
mutate(Arrived = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
     Departed = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

In this last dataset, the values of Arrived and Departed are dependent on the proportions in the df dataframe. So XX% of males aged 0-9 years would be assigned arrival status, based on the value of prob_arr in the df dataframe.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Most of the "probabilities" are greater than 1---are they percentages?

Comment: Also, are arrivals and departures independent? That is, would it make sense for a single individual to be marked as both arrived and departed?

Comment: Sorry, yes, they are in fact proportions. The third option is neither arrived nor departed. They are independent, although it would be unusual for someone to arrive and depart in the same year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that (a) the probabilities are percentages, and (b) that they are independent, here's a simple method in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
pop_df %>% left_join(df) %>%
  mutate(Arrived = as.integer(runif(n()) * 100 < prob_arr),
         Departed = as.integer(runif(n()) * 100 < prob_dep))
```

Though the same logic is just about as easy in `base`:

```
joined_df = merge(pop_df, df)
transform(
  joined_df,
  Arrived = as.integer(runif(nrow(joined_df)) * 100 < prob_arr),
  Departed = as.integer(runif(nrow(joined_df)) * 100 < prob_dep)
)
```

Comment: Thanks Gregor. Arrivals and Departures are not independent, so I edited this slightly to : `pop_df %>%
   left_join(df) %>%
  mutate(Arrived = as.integer(runif(n()) * 100 < prob_arr)) %>%
  mutate(Departed = case_when(Arrived == 0 ~ as.integer(runif(n())*100 < prob_dep),
                                              TRUE ~ 0))`

Comment: No need for `case_when` when you only have one case, I would do `mutate(Arrived = as.integer(runif(n()) * 100 < prob_arr)), Departed = as.integer(runif(nrow(joined_df)) * 100 < prob_dep & !Arrived))`. But this will underestimate departures, as it will make the departures a percentage of *those who didn't arrive* rather than of the whole population. Let me know if that's concerning and I can edit with a better fix.

Comment: On the other hand your comment on the question said "*it would be unusual for someone to arrive and depart in the same year*", so you might want to leave it as-is. With your probabilities on the order of 1%, the probability of someone arriving and departing will be about 1% * 1% = 0.01%, which is indeed pretty unusual. If you do the fix as in the comments above, it will be 0%.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Gregor. I think I may have explained this incorrectly, because when I run this code I am not getting the volumes of migrants I am expecting. For each combination of age and gender, I have a set number of people that departed or arrived in a year. I would expect that after running the code you provided, the number of people expect to have arrived or departed would be equal to the aggregate observed number. But this is not the case.

Comment: I don't understand this comment. Let's make it more specific. The first row of your `df` shows males in the age range of 0-9, and gives a `prob_arr` of 1.45. Now, this doesn't make sense as a strict *probability*, as probabilities and proportions **must be between 0 and 1**. So, I've assumed this is a *percentage, i.e., 1.45% = 0.0145 proportion (or probability). So, what my code does, is give each male in the age group 0-9 in the big `pop_df` a probability 0.0145 chance of being flagged for arrival....

Comment: There is randomness, of course, so it will not result in *exactly* 1.45% of that population being flagged as arrival---just like if I flip a fair coin 10 times I will not be surprised if I don't get *exactly* 5 heads---but it will average out, and especially on the ~5M sample size you mention it should be quite close. If you intend something else, then please edit your question to correct my misunderstandings.

Comment: (And, while I appreciate the vote of confidence, in the future you may want to hold off on "accepting" answers until you're pretty sure they're working.)

Comment: Thanks Gregor. I figured it out. Because my original data (prob_arr and prob_dep) are percentages, I don't need the *100. The final code I used is below. The volumes of migrants observed and predicted are nearly identical. Thank you very much.

Comment: `library(dplyr)
pop_df %>% left_join(df) %>%
  mutate(Arrived = as.integer(runif(n()) < prob_arr),
         Departed = as.integer(runif(n()) < prob_dep) & !Arrived)`